# how to perform a linear approximation and get linear equation from an array of data in python

Tags: python, numpy, matplotlib, pandas, scipy

I want to know how is it possible to perform a linear approximation and get the linear equation from the array of data in python.

i.e. It would be something like

```
linapprox((0,0),(1,1),(2,1.9),(3,3.1))
> y = x
```

Comment: http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.linalg.lstsq.html

Comment: [`numpy.linalg.lstsq`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.linalg.lstsq.html) might help you there.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

[`polyfit`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.polyfit.html) would work

```
x=np.arange(0,4)
y=np.array([0,1,1.9,3.1])
np.polyfit(x,y,1)
```

Gives

```
array([ 1.02, -0.03])
```

The two values are m and c where y = mx + c

You could round this:

```
np.round(np.polyfit(x,y,1))
```

to give what you wanted:

```
array([ 1.,  0.])
```

Comment: Interesting.. why did you use `polyfit` vs `linalg.lstsq`?

Comment: Force of habit... it's what I found first when I had a similar problem. Would be interested in opinion as to which is best.

Comment: Unsurprisingly, polyfit uses lstsq in the end (line 1377)... https://github.com/numpy/numpy/blob/v1.8.1/numpy/polynomial/polynomial.py#L1195